# What are typical insurance costs for airliners?

Tags: insurance

What are typical insurance costs for airliners, and how are they arrived at?

Factors that might be relevant are hours flown, number of landings/takeoffs per year, total hours of airframe and engines, hours on type for the pilot in command, etc. - but are they considered, and how?

Also, are long-haul flights treated differently than short-haul?

Obviously, each specific contract is covered by commercial confidentiality, but some baseline estimates should be available somewhere.

Comment: you are talking about commercial airliners, right , because i guess that the insurance will  vary with personal, on commercial

Answer (score 1):

for personal airplanes(like a Cessna),

> Expect to pay anywhere from $600 per year and up depending on the airplane, your time in type and total hours.

source (http://www.planeviz.com/cost-of-aircraft-ownership-ep-9/)

while there are no estimates (that i can find) about the really big commercial airplanes like the 747, there are estimates available for smaller airplanes like the G650 ( [image: G650] )

the estimate for this plane in insurance is 60,000 USD per year

source (https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-yearly-maintenance-and-total-overhead-charges-for-a-65-million-Gulfstream-G650)